# Where is sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)^n$ analytic

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve for the values of $z$ such that the function $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\dfrac{1-z}{1+z}\right)^n$$ converges, and also determine where the sum is analytic.

Well, the series converges if and only if $\left|\dfrac{1-z}{1+z}\right|<1$, which means $|1-z|<|1+z|$. Viewing geometrically, $z$ is closer to the point $1$ than to the point $-1$, so we have $\Re{z}>0$.

Where is the sum analytic? I don't know of any theorem to guarantee that.

Comment: A possible direction would be to use standard theorems about differentiability of series of functions, and the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the half-space $\Re(z) > 0$, your function is nothing but
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)^n = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1-z}{1+z}} = \frac{1+z}{2z}
$$
which is analytic on $\Re(z) > 0$.

Also, the series does not converges at all if $\Re(z) \leq 0$ (check this).

Comment: Thanks. You mean the series can also converge on $\Re{z}=0$? I thought if $|w|=1$, then $1+w+w^2+\ldots$ does not converge.

Comment: @MikaH. I don't mean that at all: the series cannot converge since its general term does not tend towards 0. see my edit.

Comment: Of course, you can analytically continue the function so that it's $\frac{1+z}{2z}$ everywhere.

Comment: @Siméon I see. For $\Re{z}\leq 0$, the series does not converge for the simple reason you mentioned: Its general term does not tend toward $0$. :)